# Como remover o destaque do column header, quando filtrado, no grid panel em Ext Js?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs-4

Tenho usado o column header do grid panel em Ext Js, e aplicado filtros nas colunas através do seu drop-down menu de filtros.

[image: Column headers with no filters applied]

Toda vez que eu aplico um filtro à coluna pelo menu, o título da coluna fica em destaque (com as letras sublinhadas e em negrito).

Tenho tentado encontrar uma maneira de remover o destaque (como em Project Name na foto) por meio de código, para que toda vez que um filtro seja aplicado à uma coluna, o destaque de todas as outras colunas seja removido. Dessa forma, apenas uma coluna por vez fica destacada.

[image: Applying text filter to the column header]

[image: Column headers with 1 filter applied to column "Project Name"]

Já procurei a documentação e não encontrei nenhum evento ou método que eu possa usar para remover esse destaque que o grid aplica ao column header. Quero que seja impossível ter 2 colunas com destaque no título ao mesmo tempo.

[image: Column headers with 2 filter applied at the same time]

Existe alguma maneira de implementar isso? Ainda, existe alguma config que eu possa usar para remover a aplicação desse destaque (para que as colunas nunca fiquem destacadas)?

Obs: Estou aplicando um store.clearFilter() toda vez que o filtro de coluna é modificado, e o header ainda não volta ao normal.

Comment: Perdão! Já editei para o português.

Comment: Faltou o título

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a id on the Columns and after that. Use CSS to remove it.

```
 #columns-from-menu
  {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
```

And if it dont help you, try to put "!important" after styles.

```
 #columns-from-menu
  {
    font-style: normal!important;
    font-weight: 200!important;
    font-size: 16px!important;
    text-decoration: none!important;
  }
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Luti. Aonde eu consigo acessar a classe CSS que eu posso aplicar essas definições?

Comment: Luti, estamos no Stack Overflow em Português, por favor traduza sua pergunta.